# Convert double to int in inline-text

Tags: jsf, casting, converters

```
<o:importFunctions type="java.lang.Math" />//omnifaces, see http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/importFunctions
<c:set var="ordersToShow" value="${Math:min(5, processedOrders.size())}" /> // processedOrders is a List
<p:fieldset legend="Last Stuff (${ordersToShow})">[...]</p:fieldset>
```

${ordersToShow} is of type java.lang.Double (output of "${ordersToShow.class}") and prints sth. like "Last Stuff 2.0".

I want to have the output like "Last Stuff 2", how can I do that?

Comment: Why exactly is it double instead of integer in first place? How exactly does it make sense to have a field representing an "amount" to be of double type? Your root problem is the wrong data model, not the troublesome presentation.

Comment: You are right somehow, as with a correct dataModel I would not have this problem. I updated the question to explain my problem better. As you can see, I cannot change the data model, as "ordersToShow" is created within the template. Thanks for your omnifaces::importFunctions. It is really strange, that Math:min seems to return a double for (int, int)-input. Anyhow, IMO should this requirenment "'cast'to int in jsf-template" be possible anyway.

Answer (score 0):

f:convertNumber will throw error ( Parent not an instance of ValueHolder) for p:fieldSet if its used inside.

Instead you can keep an string in managed bean and in its getter you can use `String.format("%.0f", ordersToShow);`

Else keep an binding variable for fieldSet and set the above formatted value in bean.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will do this in last resort, but my hope is the solve this view-equirement within the view.

Answer (score -1):

You can use f:convertNumber. Keeping minFractionDigits="0" should do the trick.

See here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_convertnumber_tag.htm

I have not used p:fieldset so now sure how the f:convertNumber can be used with the legend but seems not possible.

You can use this, replace c:set and p:fieldset lines with the below. The fmt tag explained here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_format_formatnumber_tag.htm

```
<fmt:formatNumber var="ordersToShow" type="number" maxFractionDigits="0" value="${...}" />
<p:fieldset legend="Last Stuff (${ordersToShow})">[...]</p:fieldset>
```

Comment: Where exactly would I have to add the converter?

Comment: `<fmt:xxx>` is [not available](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/) in Facelets at all.

Comment: I mentioned about jstl tag library. But similar tag is available there f:convertNumber

Comment: Please post answers which works 100% based on own experience and/or knowledge of "under the covers" workings, not on wild guesses and shoot-in-the-darks.

Comment: @BalusC We *must* include that quotation of yours in the FAQ :)